# chartjs vertical scrubber line when hovering over a line and when click

Tags: javascript, charts

is there a way to get a vertical scrubber line when hovering over a line and when click let the line shown and get the point data in console.log using chart.js 4.3.0? Similar to the way a vertical line appears in the example [chartjs image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFUaE.png)

I can use tool tips on the actual points along the line, but it'd like to be able to have a vertical line appear as the user hovers and click over the chart and scrubs left to right